# Eclipse - how to auto-close quotation mark

Tags: eclipse

I thought this was the default behavior, but my Java editor refuses to auto complete quotation marks, even though it will auto-complete parentheses and brackets.

For example, when I type

```
list.add("
```

it refuses to auto-complete.

Is there a place to set this in Eclipse preferences?  It seems like there are about 7,000 sub menus, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, auto-completion *is* the default behavior, at least as of Helios version, so maybe yours got disabled by accident? I found the setting in Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing. Near the top I have an "Automatically close" fieldset that includes "Strings". Hopefully that clears up the issue.

Just to be very explicit: When I type

```
list.add("
```

what I see is

```
list.add("")
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right spot.  I like a lot of things about Eclipse, but the menus are a maze!